# Sticky menu is not working (show)when I set the window scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on the sticky menu. it is initially hidden and I want to show that when users scroll down or up the page and leave the main menu.
Here is my Jquery code:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {

     if ($(this).scroll() >= 100) {
           $("#sticky").show();
       } else {
           $("sticky").hide();
       }
 });
```

I have attached the image to make it more clear ! ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN8Ck.png)

Comment: use scrollTop() function instead of scroll(). it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  Function

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
     $("#sticky").show();
  } else {
    $("sticky").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks , it did work I also  want it disappears when the user scroll up and see the main top menu

Comment: by the way we should change the $(document) to $(window)